# Vuetify v-btn click event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am using vuetify and I am trying to call a method when v-btn component clicked. But it seems it is not working.

it is my code:

```
<v-btn @click="bookmarkSave()">
    <v-icon v-if="!isBookmarked">bookmark_border</v-icon>
    <v-icon v-else>bookmark</v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

and I declared a method in the component (in methods section) like that:

```
bookmarkSave : async function () {
                  const response = await axios.get('api/bookmark-kaydet?voice_id=' + this.audio.id);
                 console.log(response);
               }
```

but I couldn't call bookmarkSave() method on click event. Also, I tried .native option, too. Are there any idea what is wrong with my code? or who want to show me use click event on v-btn component

When I click button, there are no console eror or network log. I can see only some output on vue tool. I added an image about that.
[image]

Comment: Is `bookmarkSave` in the `methods` section of your component?  Do you have multiple `methods` secrtions?

Comment: @StevenSpungin yes, it is on methods section, and I have only one methods section.

Comment: i dont think this is issue, but you dont nees () in @click unless u are passing params, which you dont

Comment: Your method is getting called then and the problem is the axios call.  Put a log before the axios call.  And add a catch handler to the `await`.

Comment: are you getting anything in console? try adding some other function that is not async just to see if it works than on click.

Comment: @MladenSkrbic I tried it without "()" and not an async function. it is same. there are no error on console.

Comment: its seems that your click is working, check if your api endpoint is correct, and try to catch error and see what is says

Comment: check in console, not in vue devtools

Comment: nope, ı tried it without api call. I tried to call a sync method includes only console.log('xxx') . click event is not called method. there are no log on console.

Comment: so if you do `<v-btn @click="bookmarkSave">` and in your methods you do `methods: { test: function() { console.log('test') } }` you don't even see "test" in the console?

Comment: @MichaelCacciano nope. I coudlnt see any result with    ````<v-btn @click="test"> methods: { test: function() { console.log('test') } }````

Comment: if you can't even log something simple from a method there might be an issue somewhere else in the code or in the component that is stopping the code from even getting there properly

Comment: Ok, thank you guys, I will investigate it. If I found problem, I will inform u. thanks again.

Comment: @HayreddinTüzel did you solve it?

Comment: Interesting problem, @HayreddinTüzel may be you can check the `render` function generated by Vue.js, see what's wrong in it. Also, set a breakpoint and debug step by step.

Answer (score 2):

Attaching .native to the @click, as @click.native="func" worked for me since the underlying component does not have this event natively.

You can, also, wrap your component into a native html element which has this feature, i.e. a div.

Hope I could help!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem.

The solution for me was to stop propagation of the click event:

```
<v-btn @click.stop="showInput = false">
```

I had the following structure:

```
<v-list> 
  <v-list-item @click="showInput = true">
     ....
     <v-btn @click="showInput = false">
     ....
```

While clicking on the list item worked flawlessly, clicking the button didn't work. What happend is that the click event propagated to the list item and resert showInput to true.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/35#issuecomment-269239541

When used on a component, v-on now only listens to custom events $emitted by that component. To listen for a native DOM event on the root element, you can use the .native modifier. For example:

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.