# Modifying v-model from Wrapper's Sub Component not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

VueJS 2, Vuetify 2

So I'm trying to create wrapper components (so we can upgrade Vue and Vuetify easier) and I want to add some base functionality within the wrapper. In this case, it's a v-bottom-sheet with a default close button. I cannot get the close button to even register it's been clicked, let alone actually close the v-bottom-sheet.

Parent

```
<base-bottom-sheet v-model="openSheet>Text here</base-bottom-sheet>
```

I've tried two ways to get the button click to work, both unsuccessfully

Child - using v-bind, v-on

```
<template>
    <v-bottom-sheet v-bind="$attrs" v-on="$listeners">
        <v-sheet>
            <v-btn @click="onClick">X</v-btn> <!-- not even sure what to try here-->
            <slot></slot>
        </v-sheet>
    </v-bottom-sheet>
</template>
<script>
import { VBottomSheet } from 'vuetify/lib';
import { VSheet } from 'vuetify/lib';
import { VBtn } from 'vuetify/lib';

export default {
    name: 'BaseBottomSheet',
    props: {
        scrollable: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        },
    },
    methods: {
        onClick(value) {
            console.log("V", value) //this doesn't even work
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Child - using defined value prop

```
<template>
    <v-bottom-sheet :value="value" v-on="$listeners">
        <v-sheet>
            <v-btn :value=value @click="$emit('input', $event)">X</v-btn> <!-- not working -->
            <slot></slot>
        </v-sheet>
    </v-bottom-sheet>
</template>
<script>
<script>
import { VBottomSheet } from 'vuetify/lib';
import { VSheet } from 'vuetify/lib';
import { VBtn } from 'vuetify/lib';

export default {
    name: 'BaseBottomSheet',
    props: {
        scrollable: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        },
        value: Boolean
    }
};
</script>
```

---

It's working! Here's what I did :) Thanks Estus for the pointers

```
<template>
    <v-bottom-sheet :value="value" v-bind="$attrs" v-on="$listeners">
        <v-sheet>
            <v-btn :value="value" @click="onClick">X</v-btn>
            <slot></slot>
        </v-sheet>
    </v-bottom-sheet>
</template>
<script>
import { VBottomSheet } from 'vuetify/lib';
import { VSheet } from 'vuetify/lib';
import { VBtn } from 'vuetify/lib';

export default {
    name: 'BaseBottomSheet',
    props: {
        scrollable: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        },
        value: {
            type: [Boolean, PointerEvent]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onClick(value) {
             this.$emit('input', !this.value);
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Can you help me with getting the button to work or am I just trying to do too much in the wrapper?

Edit: Simplified 'the-close-button' to 'v-btn' since that part is irrelevant to the issue and also tried to make MCVE

Comment: What is the-close-button and why do you expect it to work? The question needs  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've updated my code to be MCVE and removed the-close-button since it isn't needed for the issue

Comment: It's relevant because this totally depends on a comp with click event. It should support it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56722576/vuetify-v-btn-click-event

Comment: Okay wow. You're right, thank you! Now that the click registers, can you help point to which direction ahead is better and how to actually change the value so that the bottom-sheet closes?

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to figure it out. Thanks!